# Apache POI insert image without anchor

Tags: apache-poi, insert-image

I'm creating Excel file in Java using Apache POI, it works but the inserted image is anchored to columns / rows. There are 2 issues with this method:

1. The image doesn't keep the original size (get stretched a little bit).
2. When resizing the columns/rows the image get stretched. Is there any way to insert an image to Excel without anchor? (same as using Excel / Insert / Picture)

I'm using the following example from Apache POI document page:

```
//create a new workbook
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(); //or new HSSFWorkbook();

//add picture data to this workbook.
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("image1.jpeg");
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
int pictureIdx = wb.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
is.close();

CreationHelper helper = wb.getCreationHelper();

//create sheet
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();

// Create the drawing patriarch.  This is the top level container for all shapes. 
Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

//add a picture shape
ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
//set top-left corner of the picture,
//subsequent call of Picture#resize() will operate relative to it
anchor.setCol1(3);
anchor.setRow1(2);
Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);

//auto-size picture relative to its top-left corner
pict.resize();

//save workbook
String file = "picture.xls";
if(wb instanceof XSSFWorkbook) file += "x";
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I found solution to number 2:
    anchor.setAnchorType(ClientAnchor.DONT_MOVE_AND_RESIZE);

Comment: Did you manage to fix #1 problem?

Answer (score 1):

Proably that because of this comment in method 'resize' javadoc:

> Please note, that this method works correctly only for workbooks with the default font size (Arial 10pt for .xls and Calibri 11pt for .xlsx). If the default font is changed the resized image can be streched vertically or horizontally.